# I completed The Raid and no thane dialogue options

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I go to do The Raid quest. Not only to not get the actual quest but a misc objective, I also get no dialogue options related to thaneship, neither did I get a Blade if the Rift. Anyone have an idea why this happened?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here that might be contributing to your problem. Firstly, "The Raid" quest is a multi-part side quest that can mess up at either point.

The Raid/Supply and Demand [bugs](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Raid#Bugs):

- If the meeting spot was recently cleared out at the Riften Warehouse before the quest was given, then Sarthis' bag in the locked room where the written shipment manifest is located might be missing. This is needed to finish the quest.
- If Cragslane Cavern has been cleared prior to beginning this quest, eliminating the enemies there may not update the quest objective "Disrupt the Skooma trade." In order to complete this objective a total of seven bandits must be killed. The bandits do respawn (three each time, the first guard standing outside the cave, the second guarding the interior entrance and third being the chief bandit). Thus, killing the three bandits, then returning to the cave later and killing the respawned bandits allows the objective to eventually be completed.
- Sometimes, picking up the shipment manifest does not progress the quest, and the dialogue options will not be available with the Jarl. The objective marker will still lead to Sarthis' bag, asking the Dragonborn to retrieve the evidence, even if the note is in their inventory. This can be fixed by placing the note back in the bag or just drop it and then picking it up again. 
  An alternate solution is to read the manifest. This should also continue the quest.

[Requirements for "I done got Thaned"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/I_Done_Got_Thaned!#Objectives):

- Befriend the Jarl of the Rift.
- Assist five citizens of the Rift.
- Stop the Skooma trade.
- Purchase Honeyside.
- Return to the Jarl.

Make sure you've completed all of these as well, in order to become Thane of Riften.